# Windows Azure + Windows Phone 8 + Mobile Service

Tags: windows-phone-8

How use windows azure from WP 8?

Code from windows azure

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
"https://zzzzz.azure-mobile.net/", "xi.....");
```

Login code

```cs
var user = await mobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
```

On WP show microsoft page "can`t connect try later" on russian. Can I get this page on english?

Comment: Do you want to make it work or show the errors in english?

Comment: I want to make it work. And I want get errors on english too.

Comment: Do you have correct client secret in the identity tab of the azure console? Do you saved it in the MicrosoftAccount field?